# How do I calculate the sum of the points in a HighChart after I edit it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart with drag-able points similar to this example, http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/, except I am only using an area-spline chart. The series of points is taken from this array `data = [1,5,3,8,12]`

Before I drag any of the points on the graph, I calculate the sum of points on the curve, I get 29. However, I need to calculate the sum of the points after I move the points on the graph. What is the best way to do this? I have been going in circles for ages and I can't seem to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for the Stacked bars:

```
var dataItem = chart.series[X].data[Y],
    dataValue = dataItem.percentage/100*dataItem.total;
```

for the line-graph, you should be able to do:

```
dataValue = dataItem.y;
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/720/

```
$("#sum").text(series.data.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a + b.y;
},0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not using the Stacked bars, but could you expand on the one for the line graph? Am I correct in saying DataValue would just return the y axis position for the point I move? How would I then add that new value to the sum of the other points?

Comment: Yes, the y value is the data value. You would probably want to just redo the sum each time. Otherwise you'd have to subtract the previous value of that point before adding the new value (which means keeping track of it, and additional overhead).